# How to disable the buffer with completion options after hiting `tab` in Slime's REPL?

Tags: auto-complete-mode, slime

I have been using `company` for tab completion. It has been great while editing files.

Unfortunately, when I am using a buffer with the SLIME's REPL something annoying happens. As I start typing some function name, e.g.: `list-bookmarks`, Emacs creates a new buffer showing this info:

```lisp
Click on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
list-bookmarks
list-bookmarks-after-hook
list-bookmarks-before-hook
```

Almost always, I will ignore this information. Thus, I would like to disable it.

I would like to have only `company` working on SLIME's REPL. It is already being shown in the status bar as an active mode.

Observation: this "problem" does **not** if I use `M-/`. It only happens if I use `tab`. Since I am a heavy user of `tab`, I would like to tweak it without chaning bindings on `M-\`·

My bet is that I need to disable some hook in my config. Is my instinct correct? What exactly should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of things to unpack here.  Let me reframe what you're actually asking.

> I have been using company for tab completion.

You have been using *company for completion*.  Company-mode is a minor mode. It can be enabled locally or globally.  You don't press any key for the completion to start. You simply wait `company-idle-delay` seconds, and it starts completing (i.e. the drop-down menu appears). Notice, however, that there's a `company-active-map`.  That's a set of keybindings enabled IF AND ONLY IF the completion has already started. Indeed, (by default) hitting `TAB` runs `company-complete-common`.  Let me make this clear: hitting `TAB` BEFORE the completion runs `completion-at-point`, i.e. the built-in (extremely powerful and underrated) Emacs completion system.

Although company is part of emacs, there's no documentation (afaik). How did I study it?  By reading the source code. If you're unsure where to start: [visit its homepage](https://company-mode.github.io/); `M-x find-library RET company RET`; `C-h f company-mode RET`.

Now it should be clear that what you're really asking is: is there a way to disable the built-in Emacs completion? Well, yes. Do you really need that?  No.  Don't hit `TAB` before company starts doing its thing.  If you'd like it to start faster, tweak `company-idle-delay`.

Notice that you don't need to use `M-/` when `company-mode` is active. What `M-/` suggests is part of company's completion.  In proper terms, `dabbrev` is a company backend by default.